# detect currently selected input field in javascript for bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am trying to write a bookmarklet that fills the currently selected field in with a function of today's date.  How do I find the currently tabbed to or selected input field using javascript?

Answer (score 1):

To get the active element you can use

```
var input = document.activeElement;

if (input.tagName == "INPUT" || input.tagName == "TEXTAREA")
{
    input.value = "today's date";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`document.activeElement`

To get the current active element.

Then you can use it to input the data, like so

```
if (document.activeElement.nodeName === 'INPUT') {
   document.activeElement.value = new Date().getTime();
}
```

But your better off adding a `focus` event to the element